# I need to see the time taken by certain APIs in the test plan in jmeter

Tags: time, jmeter, output

There are multiple requests in the test plan created for ride booking process. I need to find the time taken between the login and the ride booking apis .Is there a way wherein I can get these details in the test plan automatically without any manual intervention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you're looking for the [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller), it generates synthetic Sample Result with the response time which is the sum of all its children

[image]

More information: [What is JMeter’s Transaction Controller?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-transaction-controller)